# push notification repearting for every second

Tags: android, push-notification, android-service, android-broadcastreceiver

Hi guys i am trying to create the push notification using the alarm manager where push notification must come at morning 8AM everything is good but notification is also coming but after 8AM notification is completed the notification coming when ever i open the App or clear from recents or for every one hour notification is coming please help me out facing this problem from last 1 Week

MainActivity.class

```
am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
            Intent notificationintent = new Intent(this, Notify.class);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 100, notificationintent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
            notificationintent.setData((Uri.parse("custom://"+System.currentTimeMillis())));
            Calendar calnotify = Calendar.getInstance();
            Calendar now=Calendar.getInstance();
            //Time Alaram manager
            calnotify.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 10);
            calnotify.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 00);
            calnotify.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
            if (now.after(calnotify)){
                calnotify.add(Calendar.DATE,1);
            }
            am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calnotify.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);
```

Notify.class

//BroadCastReceiver class

```
public class Notify extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Intent pushservice=new Intent(context,PushNotification.class);
        pushservice.setData((Uri.parse("custom://"+System.currentTimeMillis())));
        context.startService(pushservice);
    }

}
```

PushNotification.class

```
public class PushNotification extends Service {


  @Nullable
  @Override
  public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
      return null;
  }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Resources resources = getResources();
        getnotify(resources);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
        super.onStart(intent, startId);
        Resources resources = getResources();
        getnotify(resources);
        /*Notify notify=new Notify();
        notify.abortBroadcast();*/
    }

    private void getnotify(Resources resources) {
        Bitmap icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resources,
                R.drawable.sr_notification_icon);
        PugNotification.with(this)
                .load()
                .title(getResources().getString(R.string.app_name))
                .message("Latest Chitka")
                .bigTextStyle(getResources().getString(R.string.app_name))
                .smallIcon(getNotificationIcon())
                .largeIcon(icon)
                .flags(android.app.Notification.DEFAULT_ALL).autoCancel(true).click(MyCalendarActivity.class)
                .simple()
                .build();

    }

    private int getNotificationIcon() {
        boolean useWhiteIcon = (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP);
        return useWhiteIcon ? R.drawable.sr_icon : R.drawable.sr_notification_icon;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the code for setting alarm is executing multiple times as it is called from the main Activity of the application. You should set a flag that gets set to true once the alarm is set. Next time skip the alarm setting based on this flag.

Comment: means i must use shared preference Boolean values but how can change for next days alarm sir

Comment: Yes, you should use SharedPreference. The AlamaManager setRepeating should take care of next days alarm.

Comment: Sir ,if(boolean==false){here alaram manager method} if i write like this it wont be any problem to the alaram repeating na sir

Comment: It should not be problem.